While Compiling using nuitka getting errors
Nuitka: Running C compilation via Scons.
Nuitka-Scons: Backend C compiler: gcc (gcc 13.2.0).
module.aiohttp.cookiejar.c:13067:18: error: 'MAKE_GENERATOR_aiohttp$cookiejar$$$function__15___iter__$$$genobj__1___iter__' defined but not used [-Werror=unused-function]
13067 | static PyObject *MAKE_GENERATOR_aiohttp$cookiejar$$$function__15___iter__$$$genobj__1___iter__(struct Nuitka_CellObject **closure) {
|                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1.exe: all warnings being treated as errors
scons: *** [module.aiohttp.cookiejar.o] Error 1
FATAL: Failed unexpectedly in Scons C backend compilation.
Nuitka:WARNING:     Complex topic! More information can be found at https://nuitka.net/info/scons-backend-failure.html
Nuitka:WARNING: Report writing was prevented by exception TypeError('cannot serialize 10 (type int)'), use option '--experimental=debug-report-traceback' for full
Nuitka:WARNING: traceback.
Nuitka-Reports: Compilation crash report written to file 'nuitka-crash-report.xml'.
Getting this while compiling using nuitka

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
